# Meteor - Multi File Select UI to CollectionFS

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, multifile-uploader, meteor-collection2

I've been using yogiben/meteor-autoform-file, which is pretty awesome for uploading files directly to CollectionFS! However, uploading many files is a pain for the user: The user has to click the "+" icon once for each file to upload, and then select each file individually.

I could also use something like Blueimp JQuery File Upload for the multi-file select, but then the files don't get written to CollectionFS.

Is there an easy way to do multi-file select and have the files written to CollectionFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads in a previous project. It supports collection-fs, has drag-n-drop and multiple files features. Maybe not as simple to put in place than yogiben's package but still. Take a look as it might fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I tried it out, and found the files were uploading to the server.  But how do I get them into CollectionFS?

Comment: If you are using solutions such as GridFS, it won't work as the package needs to write it physically on the server. Some way to use it along CollectionFS + GridFS would be very nice.